# Most current iOS version distribution percentage?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, ios-3.x

I started working on a new app and I wanted to use all of the new iOS5 features (including storyboard) but I'm afraid to limit my app to iOS5 users only.

I couldn't find any information about iOS5 usage VS iOS<5 usage.

If you could point me to some research data or give me an advice about going for iOS5 only development, I would be forever grateful :)

Thanks

Comment: I wish someone could publish Flurry (or similar user tracking system) stats if they have more than one million users/downloads.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967143/where-can-i-find-ios-versions-statistics

Answer (score 24, accepted):

http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/ has some data that is (as of Apr 2013) are bang up to date.

That data showed that 1.5 weeks after formal release, iOS 6 had already reached 38%. Currently (Apr 2013) it shows that iOS 6 has reached 89.1%.

**UPDATE - June 2013**

Apple have now also added some stats to their [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/), these show the devices accessing the appstore and for a 14 day period ending June 3, 2013 iOS 6 was 93%, iOS5 6% and earlier iOS versions 1%.   (Nov 2013: this link doesn't seem to work anymore - I can't find a current link.)

**UPDATE - November 2013**

Mixpanel trends have a [graph showing iOS 7 adoption rate](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_7/from_date:-56,to_date:0)

**UPDATE - Deccember 2013**

[Apple's stats are back](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/) (at a new URL).

They're currently show iOS 7 74%, iOS 6 22%, and 'earlier' 4% - as measured by the App Store in 7 days ending 1st December. (ie. approx 2 months after the public release of iOS 7.)

Comment: The new URL takes you to a page that's empty except for the top nav bar. This confused me to start with. Then I logged in to the developer portal / member centre and tried the URL again ... and the page content all showed up. Hopefully, this will have been obvious to everyone else, but just in case... :)

Answer (score 15):

I'd say go for iOS 5: according to [this](http://yoursn0w.com/ios-4-x-reaches-90-user-base-adoption-according-to-developer-stats/) article from last year, adoption of iOS 4 was at 90+% about 6 months after release. If iOS 5 follows at the same rate, and considering it was already at 40% only a few months after release, I'd say that the numbers are somewhat similar to iOS 4. The only thing that will drive the numbers slightly down will be the real old devices that won't get iOS 5, but I'd estimate that 75%+ already have iOS 5 and it will keep growing, especially as users replace their old models with new ones.

Edit: found [this](http://www.quora.com/What-proportion-of-all-iPhone-owners-use-iOS4-*-today) other about Bump users for December where 5.0.1+5.0 would total slightly over 60%.

Also, if you're new to iPhone Dev, iOS 5 makes it much easier with ARC and storyboards among many other features. Personally, I'm targeting iOS 5 and not looking back. Also, you may want to check an excellent iOS 5 free course in iTunesU from Stanford University: [CS193P: iPad and iPhone App Development (Fall 2011)](http://news.stanford.edu/news/2011/november/itunes-apps-class-111511.html)

Final edit: found [this article](http://www.iphonelife.com/blog/12804/when-should-you-start-building-your-mobile-apps-apples-operating-system-ios5-0) that summarizes it clearly for iOS 4 -

- 1 month  after release - 50% adoption rate
- 3 months after release - 70% adoption rate
- 6 months after release - 90% adoption rate

Comment: I'm selecting your answer as the correct one because you made the most effort. Thanks!

Comment: ok, but consider also that many old iDevice aren't allowed to install IOS 5 (e.g. iPod touch 2nd gen can upgrade to 4.2 at max). So you should just ask yourself what will your app will loose if you disable the new iOS methods? could you do the same with old iOS?

Answer (score 5):

Marco Arment [tweeted](https://twitter.com/#!/marcoarment/status/168155309569875969) recently that 92% of his users are on iOS 5.

His last [detailed analysis](http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper) is from november.

Keep in mind that Instapaper (Marco Arment's product) is relatively tech-oriented and it may not be representative of the market you're looking into.

Answer (score 3):

About two months after launch, [the author of Instapaper says that just short of 50% of users were on at least iOS 5](http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper).

Nearly three months later, I would say that's a good sign that by the time your app is ready for release, requiring iOS5 is pretty safe. (Certainly that's what I'm doing.)

But ultimately it's a judgement call. Apple don't release numbers so, to some extent, you're guessing. It doesn't matter whether *all* users have iOS5. What matters is whether the people who are likely to buy your app will have iOS5.

Answer (score 0):

There are some information here: http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57321295-37/ios-5-on-almost-40-percent-of-iphones/
It is for November, but since after that percentage should not be changed much.
In short, I would recommend to not use only iOS5 features, most people seems to use 4.x.

Comment: That's the most recent I've found too. Could be very useful to have some more fresh data.