# iOS version to be consider when developing iPhone/iPad applications

Tags: iphone, ios

What are the iOS version do i need to consider when developing iPhone application?

Based on my research, iOS 3.x, 4.x and 5.x have been considers as available iOS version. But when I consider with devices there lack devices which is running iOS 3.x. 
Can someone help me with finding trusted sources where I can find these details i.e source from Apple or something?

Answer (score 1):

From Apple themselves, 93% of users are on iOS 6:

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/

Unless you need to support the iPad 1 or the very old iPhone 3G (not 3GS), go for iOS 6! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the percentage of users in this post:

[Most current iOS version distribution percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262112/most-current-ios-version-distribution-percentage)

And then decide by yourself which version you should develope to

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im personally go for iOS 4.x and iOS 5.x. But i have been asked to prepare details which are capture from authentic places. There are lots of News and blog which discuss these details but the original sources are not authentic. By any chance have you find any link from Apple web site about there support on these iOS or iPhone devices?

Comment: There's no oficial data, or at least I havent founded